# How to set FIT view using itextsharp?

Tags: itext

I am creating 3d PDF using `.prc` file. I am able to create PDF using itext library, but the 3d model is not in fit view.
In order to make 3d model in fit view which property needs to be set?

Comment: I´m currently facing the same problem. Did you solve the problem? Could you publish your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the properties in below pdf.
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Answer (score 0):

While creating 3D stream dictionary, you need to add /OnInstantiate key into 3D stream dictionary. Value of /OnInstantiate will be reference to new  stream dictionary in which you can write your fitVisible javascript code as object stream.
You need to write javascript code to calculate camera properties according to your model bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
PdfDictionary dict3D = new PdfDictionary();
dict3D.Put(PdfName.TYPE, new PdfName("3DView"));
dict3D.Put(new PdfName("XN"), new PdfString("Default"));
dict3D.Put(new PdfName("IN"), new PdfString("Unnamed"));
dict3D.Put(new PdfName("MS"), new PdfName("U3D"));
```

Please ensure the setting the property "MS".